# Find Method Empty Array

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

I have an application with a third party plugin that handles ACL management, works fine, but I am having some issues with a isAuthorized function. The user is being passed into the function and when I debug the variable I can see all of the correct information in the dataset, but when the script executes the find query it returns empty. Here is the thing, the model I am executing the query on is apart of the plugin I am using. So I am executing a find within my application on a model that lies within my plugin. To me it isn't ideal, nonetheless I am working with a plugin that wasn't built application specific. In order to execute the find the Author added

```
App::uses('User', 'AuthAcl.Model');
```

so the find could be possible. Now that said, I tweaked one thing in the conditions part of the statement because I was getting Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous error from SQL. I started to get that error because I added some relationships to the application.

I say all that to say this - since I am loading the model via App Uses shouldn't I be able to execute a find like so

```
$this->User->Find('First');
```

I have tried that and it says I'm executing on a non object. Here is the code for that script. I need input. When I execute my script without debugging it locks me out the application, and by reading the code and debugging it I think this happens because the find is returning empty. And on another note - please bear with me - I didn't write this code, and I am in the phase of learning to understand other developers code. I am using CAKEPHP 2.3 Thanks guys!

```
public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
    App::uses('User', 'AuthAcl.Model');
    App::uses('Group', 'AuthAcl.Model');

    $authFlag = false;
    $this->set('login_user',$user);
    $userModel = new User();
    $group = new Group();
    //die(debug($user));
    $rs = $this->$userModel->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('user.id' => $user['id'])));
    die(debug($rs));
    $action = 'controllers';
    if (!empty($this->plugin)){
        $action .= '/'.$this->plugin;
    }
    $action .= '/'.$this->name;
    $action .= '/'.$this->action;


    if (!empty($rs['Group'])){
        foreach ($rs['Group'] as $group){
            $authFlag = $this->Acl->check(array('Group' => array('id' => $group['id'])), $action);
            if ($authFlag == true){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($authFlag == false && !empty($user)){
        $authFlag = $this->Acl->check(array('User' => array('id' => $user['id'])), $action);
        //die(debug($authFlag));
    }

    if ($authFlag == false && !empty($user)){
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'accessDenied', 'action' => 'index','plugin' =>'auth_acl'));
    }

    if (!empty($user)){
        $user = $userModel->find('first',array('conditions' => array('user.id' => $user['id'])));
        $this->Session->write('auth_user',$user);

        $this->request->data['auth_plugin'] = $this->plugin;
        $this->request->data['auth_controller'] = $this->name;
        $this->request->data['auth_action'] = $this->action;
    }

    return $authFlag;
}
```

}